# Not sure how to handle suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was going through the Suggested Edit review Queue and cam across a suggested edit to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29897650/4342498) on [Difference between ssl_context options in Python Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888168/difference-between-ssl-context-options-in-python-flask).  The OP has suggested an edit that links to another SO answer with more detail shown below.

[image]

Should that be an edit to the post, should it have been a comment to the answerer to add it to the answer or just a comment since there are no other comments?

Comment: It should be a comment, I think.

Comment: This is the review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7852512

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely a comment on this answer.  Let's reason why.

- The edit has not made the original answer any more readable than it already is.  It's arguably worse, because now we're going to another link that provides information we weren't explicitly seeking.
- The edit leaps off of the tangent of "security" to "here's a way to run Flask in production", which is likely not what was intended originally.
- The edit does not help answer the question.  Recall [what the question is actually asking here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29888168/1079354) - we're not looking for help setting up Flask in a production environment.

Answer (score -6):

I think this is a valid edit.

Other than removing the `[edit by OP]` I think this improves the answer and brings some related information into the correct place.  I would approve this.